# How to display html using QWebView. Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebview

How to display webpage in HTML format in console.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QWebView()
view.load(QUrl('http://example.com')
# What's next? how to do something like:
# print view.read() ???
# to display something similar to that:
# <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As QT is an async library, you probably won't have any result if you immediately try to look at the html data of your webview after calling *load*, because it returns immediately, and  will trigger the *loadFinished* signal once the result is available. You can of course try to access the html data the same way as I did in the _result_available method immediately after calling *load*, but it will return an empty page (that's the default behavior).

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView


class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        print unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your example is just great!

Comment: Thanks, but when I run this _result_available() never gets called though __init__(self) does.