# Error displaying HTML Pages using PyQt4 - QWebView

Tags: python, html, pyqt4, bokeh, qwebview

As per the following SO article: [How to display html using QWebView. Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384749/how-to-display-html-using-qwebview-python)

I modified the following code by Andrean:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        # print(unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

However, for some strange reason, I still cannot view Google within my GUI window. I get the following screen below (despite waiting 5 minutes and having full internet connectivity)

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGS3W.png)

More importantly, I'm trying to view an offline HTML file which was generated using Bokeh.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# prepare some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

# show the results
show(p)
```

Replacing the GUI script appropriately with the offline html file:

```
htmlPath = QUrl('line_example.html')
view.load(htmlPath)
```

I still cannot see the HTML file I've generated - showing the same blank window as before.

I've also tried defining htmlPath as below but they still don't work:

```
htmlPath = QUrl("file:///C:/Users/giranm/PycharmProjects/Dashboard%20Testing/lineGraph.html")

htmlPath = QUrl.fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("lineGraph.html").absoluteFilePath())
```

Any assistance to get the above working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer: [Bokeh plots do not display in QWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560342/bokeh-plots-do-not-display-in-qwebview/39562521#39562521)

TLDR: Evidently `QWebView` will not run `<script>` tags that are required to load BokehJS (which is the JavaScript library that actually does all the work to render things) Inline resources *might* be an option, though be aware that `QwebView` is not considered "supported" by Bokeh in any meaningful way.