# Bokeh plots do not display in QWebView

Tags: html, python-3.x, pyqt5, bokeh

I have following code that works on linux and my windows 7 machine even using [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) environment:

```
   # plt_file is valid html produced by Bokeh and that is correctly displayed in browser
   with open(plt_file, "r") as f:
            plot = f.read()
            # self.plot_web_view.setContent(plot)
            url = QUrl(plt_file)
            self.plot_web_view.setHtml(plot, url)
```

But when I distribute my application using `WinPyhton` my plot doesn't show up in `QWebView` and no error is raised... If I try to load random html-files into `QWebView` in my app they are displayed. I guess the issue is on `Qt` side, but I have no clue what to do...

`PyQt` version in `WinPython` is 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh is actually two libraries: a Python library "Bokeh
", and a JavaScript library "BokehJS". The JavaScript library BokehJS is actually what does all the work in the browser, and is absolutely required. A little googling turns up many links, including [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184704/qwebview-not-loading-external-javascript), which seem to indicated that `QWebView` does not load external `<script>` tags in HTML. If that is the case, you will have to find some other means to load the required BokehJS files. Another option might be to use "inline" BokehJS, which can be accomplished by one way by setting the environment variable `BOKEH_RESOURCES=inline` when you run the scripts to create the HTML files. Please be aware that this will make individual HTML output files substantially larger (BokehJS is a fairly hefty library) and additionally will defeat any caching of external scripts that modern browsers do (but maybe `QWebView` doesn't do that anyway).

Lastly, while I do hope you can find a path that works, just to be clear: `QWebView` is not a "supported" platform, in the sense that no testing is done to ensure Bokeh is compatible with `QWebView` and no guarantee of compatibility with `QWebView` is claimed.

Answer (score 0):

would this work better ?

```
   plot = ""
   with open(plt_file, "r") as f:
        plot = f.read()
   # self.plot_web_view.setContent(plot)
   url = QUrl(plt_file)
   self.plot_web_view.setHtml(plot, url)
```